# Mystery directory created during maven compile

Tags: java, spring, scala, maven, openid

I have disabled all of the plugins in my module's pom.xml file and in the parent pom.xml file.  I type

```
`mvn clean install -U`
```

and in the same directory

```
`${project.basedir}/src/main/site/resources/repo`
```

appears, approximately during the time the compile phase executes.

Any ideas about what could be causing this?

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<name>My Project</name>

<groupId>com.my</groupId>
<artifactId>my.parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>openid-connect-client</module>
    <module>openid-connect-common</module>
    <module>openid-connect-server</module>
    <module>my.libraries</module>
    <module>my.rest</module>
    <module>my.spark-utils</module>
    <module>openid-connect-server-webapp</module>
</modules>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>HortonWorks</id>
        <url>http://nexus-private.hortonworks.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.basedir>.</project.basedir>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
    <scala-version>${scala.tools.version}.7</scala-version>

    <flyway.maven.plugin.version>4.2.0</flyway.maven.plugin.version>
    <maven.war.plugin.version>3.2.2</maven.war.plugin.version>
    <maven.install.plugin.version>2.5.2</maven.install.plugin.version>

    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
    </sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    <sonar.junit.reportPaths>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportPaths>
    <findbugs.annotations.version>3.0.1</findbugs.annotations.version>
    <findbugs.jsr305.version>3.0.2</findbugs.jsr305.version>

    <scapegoat.version>1.3.5</scapegoat.version>

    <apached.server.jndi.version>1.5.5</apached.server.jndi.version>
    <aws-java-sdk.version>1.11.250</aws-java-sdk.version>

    <!-- Commons -->
    <commons-collections4.version>4.1</commons-collections4.version>
    <commons.csv.version>1.1</commons.csv.version>
    <commons.fileupload.version>1.3.3</commons.fileupload.version>
    <commons.lang3.version>3.5</commons.lang3.version>

    <elasticsearch.version>6.2.3</elasticsearch.version>
    <elasticsearch.transport.client.version>6.2.3</elasticsearch.transport.client.version>
    <lucene.version>7.3.1</lucene.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.192</h2.version>
    <jboss.logging.version>3.3.1.Final</jboss.logging.version>

    <jsoup.version>1.11.2</jsoup.version>
    <jmockit.version>1.38</jmockit.version>
    <jetty.version>9.4.14.v20181114</jetty.version>

    <sonar.scoverage.reportPath>target/scoverage.xml</sonar.scoverage.reportPath>
    <sonar.scala.scoverage.reportPath>${sonar.scoverage.reportPath}</sonar.scala.scoverage.reportPath>
    <sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPath>./target/scapegoat</sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPath>
    <sonar.scala.version>${scala-version}</sonar.scala.version>

    <!-- Guava -->
    <guava.version>22.0</guava.version>

    <!-- Snappy -->
    <snappy.version>1.0.5</snappy.version>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.14.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.oauth2.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.oauth2.version>
    <spring.security.core>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.security.core>
    <spring.security.ldap.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.security.ldap.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <!-- Hortonworks Ecosystem -->
    <hdp.version>3.0.1.0-187</hdp.version>
    <hadoop.version>3.1.1.${hdp.version}</hadoop.version>
    <hbase.version>2.0.0.${hdp.version}</hbase.version>
    <phoenix.version>5.0.0.${hdp.version}</phoenix.version>
    <spark.version>2.3.1.${hdp.version}</spark.version>
    <zookeeper.version>3.4.6.${hdp.version}</zookeeper.version>

    <!-- Spark Variant -->
    <!--<aehrc.variant.spark.version>0.2.0-a1</aehrc.variant.spark.version>-->
    <aehrc.variant.spark.version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</aehrc.variant.spark.version>

    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <!-- Environment Profiles -->
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProfile>local</activatedProfile>

            <!-- TODO: For all other env these will be stored on disk -->
            <database.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my</database.url>
            <database.user>username</database.user>
            <database.password>password</database.password>

            <postgresql.version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>aws-dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProfile>aws-dev</activatedProfile>
            <!-- TODO: For all other env these will be stored on disk -->
            <database.url>
                jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db
            </database.url>
            <database.user>user</database.user>
            <database.password>password</database.password>
            <postgresql.version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integration</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- -Dtests.security.manager=false is needed otherwise the ESTestCase fails to initialize -->
                    <configuration>
                        <!--<argLine>-Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dtests.security.manager=false</argLine>-->
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>none</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- This plugin compiles Scala files -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- The configuration is not included unless the profile is active. -->
                        <!-- This keeps the compiler plugin out of the equation and assists IntelliJ -->
                        <!-- as long as IntelliJ doesn't try to activate the sonar profile. -->
                        <configuration>
                            <scalaVersion>${scala.tools.version}</scalaVersion>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-P:scapegoat:dataDir:${sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPath}
                                </arg>
                                <arg>-P:scapegoat:reportOnly:true</arg>
                                <arg>
                                    -P:scapegoat:overrideLevels:TraversableHead=Warning:TraversableLast=Warning:OptionGet=Warning:MapGetAndGetOrElse=Warning
                                </arg>
                            </args>
                            <compilerPlugins>
                                <compilerPlugin>
                                    <groupId>com.sksamuel.scapegoat</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>scalac-scapegoat-plugin_${scala.tools.version}
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <version>${scapegoat.version}</version>
                                </compilerPlugin>
                            </compilerPlugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <highlighting>true</highlighting>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.tools.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pre-compile</goal>
                            <goal>post-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scoverage-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This plugin compiles Scala files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-scala-source</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.install.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flyway.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate>
                    <url>${database.url}</url>
                    <user>${database.user}</user>
                    <password>${database.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <spring.profiles.active>${activatedProfile}</spring.profiles.active>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.alexcojocaru</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- REPLACE THE FOLLOWING WITH THE PLUGIN VERSION YOU NEED -->
                <version>6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- REPLACE THE FOLLOWING WITH THE ELASTICSEARCH VERSION YOU NEED -->
                    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
                    <clusterName>test</clusterName>
                    <!--These ports must also be changed in "classpath:test/application.properties".-->
                    <transportPort>9301</transportPort>
                    <httpPort>9201</httpPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.14.v20181114</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.appfuse.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>warpath-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!--
                    Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>./target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
                        </destFile>
                        <!--
                            Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                            for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                        -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--
                    Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
                    unit tests have been run.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>./target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
                        </dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>./target/site/jacoco-ut
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>./target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
                        </destFile>
                        <!--
                            Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                            for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                        -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--
                    Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after
                    integration tests have been run.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>./target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
                        </dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>./target/site/jacoco-it
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-requirements</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>[3.5.3,)</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>[${java.version},)</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The child pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>my.spark-utils</artifactId>
<name>SPARK-UTILS</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <scala.override.version>2.11.7</scala.override.version>
    <guava.override.version>13.0.1</guava.override.version>
    <jetty.override.version>9.3.19.v20170502</jetty.override.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <scalaVersion>${scala.tools.version}</scalaVersion>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-P:scapegoat:dataDir:./target/scapegoat-report</arg>
                                <arg>-P:scapegoat:reportOnly:true</arg>
                                <arg>-P:scapegoat:overrideLevels:TraversableHead=Warning:TraversableLast=Warning:OptionGet=Warning:MapGetAndGetOrElse=Warning</arg>
                            </args>
                            <compilerPlugins>
                                <compilerPlugin>
                                    <groupId>com.sksamuel.scapegoat</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>scalac-scapegoat-plugin_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${scapegoat.version}</version>
                                </compilerPlugin>
                            </compilerPlugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- This plugin compiles Scala files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- This plugin compiles Java files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>it.unimi.dsi.fastutil</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>my.it.unimi.dsi.fastutil</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>my.com.google</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/license/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                            <exclude>NOTICE</exclude>
                            <exclude>/*.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>my-spark-utils</finalName>
</build>
```

I don't have enough space to include all of the dependency information.

Comment: Please post your related poms

Comment: Thanks @ngueno, I have added the poms.  There is not enough space to include all of the data.

Comment: @mrbarret - did you ever solve this problem? The Apache NiFi build has the same issue

Comment: Never solved it. And have long since been rolled to another project.